# can you add to blender icons

Tags: interface

[image]Can I add to the blender ICONS?
Where are the blender ICONS in window?

thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear. The blender icon for it's .exe file? Or all the icons within blender?

Comment: sorry, see added image. I would like to make some custom icons to add to this menu. Go to Use Pref/Development/Development: Icon Viewer. This is only some of the blender art assets.

Comment: Your suggestion is not the question I asked. Blender has a internal ICONS as seen by my attachment. Are they editable?